# What version of Blend supports WPF 4.5, Portable Class Library?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, portable-class-library

I am setting up the project structure for a new greenfield application.  Our initial release will only support a WPF client, but we want to eventually roll out Metro and Silverlight clients as well.  I decided on the following:

Core Library - Portable class library targeting .NET for metro, .NET 4.5, SL4, Windows Phone 7.5

WPF Application - Targeting .NET 4.5

Our Model/ViewModel layer is defined in the Core Library, View defined in the WPF Application.  I chose .NET 4.5 in order to support defining the viewmodel in the core library in a way that can be consumed by both WPF and Metro.

This works fine in the Visual Studio 11 Beta running on Windows 7 Pro.  I have a working view that is data bound to the ViewModel defined in the Core Library.  My problem is Blend.  When I open the View in Blend, I get no designer.  I suspect the problem here is support for WPF on .NET 4.5.  I have tried Blend 4 and Blend for VS11 Beta.

Does anyone know how to get the designer working in Blend for WPF views as described above?

*Status as of 2012-05-10:
  No combination of VS11 and Blend appear to support WPF 4.5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Visual Studio 2012, [Update 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/04/04/visual-studio-2012-update-2-now-available.aspx), the preview version of Blend ([Blend + Sketchflow Preview for VS2012](http://blendinsider.com/technical/announcing-blend-sketchflow-preview-for-visual-studio-2012-2012-08-15/)) has been merged with into the vanilla "Blend for Visual Studio 2012". This means that there is now a single designer application for all [XAML platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj171012.aspx):

> With Blend (for Visual Studio 2012), you can design and build:
>
> - Windows Store apps
> - Windows Phone apps
> - Sketchflow prototypes
> - Microsoft Silverlight and Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications

Answer (score 2):

edit: At this time, there's no Blend support for WPF 4.5.  Here's the relevant info:

You need to install Visual Studio 11 Beta (Ultimate, Premium, or Professional -- NOT Express since it lacks the Blend pieces you want) on a Windows 8 preview build.  That's just how they decided to line things up.  Even once you do this, you still won't have WPF support:

> Please be aware that in the Visual Studio beta, the XAML authoring
>   support for Windows 8 is not quite at the same level of stability and
>   completeness yet as the HTML authoring support.

Windows 8 requirement: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devschool/archive/2012/03/01/blend-5-and-visual-studio-11-awesome.aspx

Visual Studio versions: http://blendinsider.com/technical/visual-authoring-for-the-windows-8-consumer-preview-with-blend-and-visual-studio-2012-02-29/

Comment: So the only way to get the recommended development story to work is to use a non-supported configuration?  They announced go-live licensing is only supported on Windows 7.

Comment: I am running VS 11 Ultimate Beta, so it must be the Win 8 piece that is causing the trouble.

Comment: Is there a link you could give that shows those requirements?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the relevant links.  Like I said, I question their ability to ship software.  On the other hand, I spoke to someone who went to the Build conference and he was not surprised due to the deep security changes made to the upcoming version of .NET.

Comment: I setup a VM running Windows 8 consumer preview.  The designer in Blend for VS11 still does not work for WPF 4.5.  I will install and try the SL5 one tonight.

Comment: I have installed the SL5 Blend preview as well as Blend 4 Ultimate and neither allow me to edit pages in the WPF 4.5 project.

Comment: Try creating a WPF 4.5 project in the version of blend that comes with VS 11 Beta on Windows 8.  If that doesn't work, nothing will.

Comment: That version is Metro-only.  You can't make WPF apps of any kind.

Comment: I guess that's what they meant in the blog post by "Please be aware that in the Visual Studio beta, the XAML authoring support for Windows 8 is not quite at the same level of stability and completeness yet as the HTML authoring support." :(

Comment: Yeah, it just amazes me that there is absolutely NO support for using blend with WPF 4.5, and at the time NO support for a portable class library at anything less than WPF 4.5.  That is a critical failure.  Update your main post to call out that WPF 4.5 is not supported and I'll give you answer credit.

Comment: Done.  Unfortunately it's not surprising: SL5 was released 5 months ago and there's still no RTM version of Blend that supports it.